# Rails remember selection from previous page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my index.html.erb

```
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#list1">Question 1</a>
      <div id="list1">Answer </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#list2">Question 2</a>
      <div id="list2">Answer </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#list3">Question 3</a>
      <div id="list3">Answer </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#list4">Question 4</a>
      <div id="list4">Answer </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#list5">Question 5</a>
      <div id="list5">Answer </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#list6">Question 6</a>
      <div id="list6">Answer </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<%= link_to "Next", pages_feedback_path%>
```

Page controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
```

Hi there I'm trying to make a website using Ruby on Rails where users can select some items and get feedback based on their selections.

So, for example if users select list1 and list4 and click next it should take the users to the feedback page. It should give a feedback to the users saying because you chose list1 and list4 you might want to try this. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys

Comment: Why don't you have it as a form with checkboxes?

Comment: You will be able to send params to next page using form and method `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

Try some jQuery like below -

```
$('li a').click(function(){
  var next_url = $('a#Next').attr('href');
  if(next_url.match(/?/)){
    $('ul')next('a').attr('href', next_url + '&' + $(this).text() + '=true' )  
  }else{
    $('ul').next('a').attr('href', next_url + '?' + $(this).text() + '=true' )
  }
});
```

Without javascript and only html, you can submit form to url like below -

```
<%= form_tag url: pages_feedback_path, method: :get do  %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= check_box_tag 'Question 1' %> Question 1
        <div id="list1">Answer </div>
    </li>
    <li><%= check_box_tag 'Question 2' %> Question 2
        <div id="list2">Answer </div>
    </li>
    <li><%= check_box_tag 'Question 3' %> Question 3
        <div id="list3">Answer </div>
    </li>
    <li><%= check_box_tag 'Question 4' %> Question 4
        <div id="list4">Answer </div>
    </li>
    <li><%= check_box_tag 'Question 5' %> Question 5
        <div id="list5">Answer </div>
    </li>
    <li><%= check_box_tag 'Question 6' %> Question 6
        <div id="list6">Answer </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <%= submit_tag('Next') %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to do it without using javascript? I'm new to rails so just want to do it just using rails to get better at it. I'll try your suggestion sending params using form.

Comment: @ray, I have updated answer with html only solution without javascript and jquery

Comment: Cheers, so if I want to give feedback based on the selection what do I need to do in the controller?

Comment: Controller side in feedback action you can check what all `params` are coming by form submit.